# Why isn't anything visible in SVG except the foreign object?

Tags: image, svg, foreignobject

I was trying to add an animé character into a flag SVG using `<foreignObject>` tag.

It didn't show up first but I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55004652/12054524), here you go my final code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="1024" height="1024" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="m-auto w-[85%] h-auto" id="chp"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <rect width="1024" height="1024" fill="#0038A8"></rect>
    <rect width="1024" height="614.4" fill="#9B4F96"></rect>
    <rect width="1024" height="409.6" fill="#D60270"></rect>
    <path
        d="M233.068 737.937V755.486L635.976 749.335L650.912 759L696.553 744.966L649.155 730.029L635.121 738.792L233.068 737.937Z"
        fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2.82384" stroke-miterlimit="3.864"></path>
    <path
        d="M227.795 700.165L230.431 717.737L794.008 593.091L812.436 598.363L855.441 575.519L807.164 570.247L789.615 583.427L227.795 700.165Z"
        fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2.82384" stroke-miterlimit="3.864"></path>
    <path
        d="M212.864 665.073L827.33 396.452L837.873 380.637L887.029 373.632L851.052 406.996L830.844 404.36L222.528 681.767L224.262 669.443L212.864 665.073Z"
        fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2.82384" stroke-miterlimit="3.864"></path>
    <path
        d="M192.66 633.482L204.96 648.395L666.712 306.017L689.509 303.405L717.625 266.55L671.082 278.827L662.319 298.133L192.66 633.482Z"
        fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2.82384" stroke-miterlimit="3.864"></path>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
        d="M168.091 606.255L180.392 620.289L449.892 313.935L468.319 309.518L489.382 265.635L449.013 285.843L443.741 306.004L168.091 606.255Z"
        fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2.82384" stroke-miterlimit="3.864"></path>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
        d="M136.5 586.073L297.145 318.331L298.024 298.146L333.145 264.782L324.359 313.059L304.174 322.724L152.315 597.495L136.5 586.073Z"
        fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2.82384" stroke-miterlimit="3.864"></path>
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="1024" height="1024">
        <xhtml:img src="https://cdn.upload.systems/uploads/Y8u4dj8y.png" alt="Killua Zoldyck"
            width="1024" height="1024" />
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Now, everything is reversed. I mean, only the image inside `<foreignObject>` is visible and everything else is hidden. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Btw - you don't need a foreign object for the image. In SVG you can use the [<image>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) element

Comment: yeah, this one worked, thanks! can you add this as an answer so i can mark the question "solved"?